# Globally Apply extern C when compiling

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I have some code I got from here: https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api, and I want to prevent the c++ name mangling so I can use ctypes in Python to call this DLL.

Is there a way to globally apply extern "C" at the compiler level?
Is there a way to easily apply it to the .h files in the code?

Thank you

(PS I'm not a c++ developer, so excuse the lack of proper terminology)

Comment: Can `extern "C"` even *be* applied? A single overloaded function will break any attempt.

Comment: Don't use ctypes. Use a C++-aware wrapper (CLIF, SIP, SWIG, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code, there is no simple solution to your problem.  The package does not have a published C binding, only C++.

You cannot *just wrap the thing in global `extern "C"`* to create a C binding, the types and APIs are heavily C++ oriented and the DLL has mangled C++ symbols anyway.

You do not have source code to the library, but you could create a separate library with C callable functions that in turn call the C++ API of the original DLL.  It is non-trivial work, to say the least!

If your goal is to get a Python binding for the ESRI File GeoDatabase API, you can take a look at these pages:

http://libjoe.blogspot.fr/2014/02/python-wrapper-for-esri-file.html

https://code.google.com/archive/p/file-geodatabase-api-python-wrapper/

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64864/gdal-python-bindings-and-file-geodatabase-api

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think I'm going to try these 3 solutions.  I've tried to follow the code.google.com solution (swig solution), but I can't get SWIG to create a workable binder using windows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in your C++ file so you don't have to change `headerfile.h`:

```
extern "C" {
#include <headerfile.h>
}
```

Comment: This is a general idea, but inapplicable to the OP's problem.  Download the package and peek into the header files... be prepared.

Comment: Ah! I just did so. Oh Dear. So an entire new adaption layer unless there is some tool for it that somebody knows. I know of none :(

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new header file with the library interface functions, since different OS require different function exporting attributes:

```
extern "C" {
int __attribute__ (dllexport) ReturnSameValue(int avalue) // Linux
{
    return avalue
}

int __declspec(dllexport) IncreseInteger(int avalue) // Windows dll
{
    return avalue+1;
}

}
```